# Adding an extra page to URL

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for the vague title, I didnt know how to explain it better.

I have an array with links like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/page.php?page=2
    [1] => http://www.example.com/page.php?page=3
    [2] => http://www.example.com/page.php?page=4
)
```

Good, but I also need the FIRST page `?page=1`. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) will add one or more values to the beginning of an array.

```
array_unshift( $urls, "http://www.example.com/page.php?page=1" );
```

#### Example and Output:

```
// Start with our array (simplified version of yours)
$urls = array( "page=2", "page=3", "page=4" );

// Output: page=2, page=3, page=4
echo join( ", ", $urls );

// Prepend our new value
array_unshift( $urls, "page=1" );

// Output: page=1, page=2, page=3, page=4
echo join( ", ", $urls );
```

Comment: Hmm.. So use regex to read everything from `http://www.example.com/page.php?page=` and add a 1? I'll give it a go! Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Regex? Who said anything about regular expressions? Hehe. Are you saying you don't know the value of `page` at entry `0`, and you need to get that number first before you prepend a new value onto the array?

Comment: Uhh well I know about the Pony's, but just don't understand DOM so I use regex to get that first array. But your code seems to work differnt, let me see if I can debug it and adjust to my need :d

Comment: DOM has nothing to do with this. Can you state what you exactly want? Please answer the question: "Are you saying you don't know the value of page at entry 0, and you need to get that number first before you prepend a new value onto the array?"

Comment: Right. Well the problem is really the `http://www.example.com/page.php?` part since that will change for every query. So I think I need to grab the "base" of the URL, and then  do the above code?

Comment: @user1333327 I'm not really sure what you're attempting. If you need to parse those urls though you can use `parse_url()` - again, avoid regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

do not know if we we mean the same 
but push the entries in the array down and add the new page on the top

```
array_splice
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $queue = array("http://www.example.com/page.php?page=1");
     array_unshift($queue, "http://www.example.com/page.php?page=2", "http://www.example.com/page.php?page=3", "http://www.example.com/page.php?page=4");
     print_r($queue);
 ?>
```